# android studio build apk crashes only when facebook/whatsapp share! Crashing doesn't happen when signed bundle uploaded and downloaded via playstore

Tags: java, android

If installed Android Studio build apk on Android Phone, app works fine untill whatsapp/facebook images shared. Whatsapp intent for text sharing it works fine but not for sharing images. One the other hand,  if signed release bundle generated from android studio and uploaded to play-store. Then app installed from play-store working flawlessly even for sharing images via facebook/whatsapp intents.

Comment: The first step when something crashes is to look it logcat. Do you see any indication as to what happened?

Comment: @Joachim.. Crashing/Restarting not happening in Android Studio Emulator.  Build and Run works there OK. However, Whatsapp/Facebook app not installed on Emulator, sharing there cannot be tested. So,  build debug apk (unsigned one) is being installed on  actual Android Phone, app is getting installed there and working fine for all functionalities except when WhatsAPP/Facebook  shares images.

Comment: Let me check now with Gmail account  by configuring it in Emulator and then try to send images via gmail. Will update test results soon.

Comment: So? You can still look at the logs in the real device.

Comment: @Joachim.. issue got resolved. Checked logcat in emulator it self using gmail sharing. Fileprovider Uri was pointed to another app's storage. Changed it and issue now not coming. However, I would like to know how to check logs in real device. any pointer ??

Comment: Using `adb logcat`. Google it for details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.